# Русс.-итальянская пара ПЕРЕМЕЛЮ - PER-MOLO

Tags: этимология

Эта русско-латинская пара интересна тем, что русское слово **ПЕРЕМЕЛЮ** (ПЕРЕМОЛОТЬ) содержит приставку (**ПЕРЕ**-).

Возникает вопрос: в латинском слове **PERMOLO** ("перемалывать") есть приставка **PER**-?
Или это слово не имеет приставки?

Каким образом и в латинском, и в русском существуют эти столь похожие слова?

И, главное, почему об этом случае молчат этимологи?
Хотя бы ради любопытства, как пример языкового курьеза, могли бы и рассказать о нем.

Comment: Знаете в чем ценность приведенной мной пары ПЕРЕМЕЛЮ-PERMOLO ?

Это то "редкое" слово, которое Фасмер не увидел, да и не мог увидеть.
Почему? Потому, что поиск родственных (заимствованных) пар между русским (славянским) и "западноевропейским" языками этимологами проводится, в основном, без учета приставок. А это - целый пласт новых пар. В нашем случае, не смотря на всю очевидность пары ПЕРЕМЕЛЮ-PERMOLO, никакому дипломированному лингвисту и в голову не может придти мысль о заимствовании. Однако, оно - налицо.

Comment: Например, Фасмер рассматривает только русск. МОЛОТЬ, что сильно сужает область поиска. Поэтому он нашел лишь лат. MALLEUS в значении "молот", "колотушка", и только. Посмотреть шире он не догадался.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу никакого курьёза. Русский и итальянский(как и латынь, испанский, ретороманский, французский, все романские и  германские языки, балтские, славянские, армянский, языки Индии, переднеазиатские и т.д. и т.д.) - относятся к индоевропейской языковой семье.  Много  общего, и в семантике, и в лексике, и в этимологии. На мой взгляд - обычное дело.

Об общих корнях:   http://www.masterperevoda.ru/news/obshii_koren_indoevropeyskih_yazikov.php

Comment: Мне трудно комментировать сведения в приведенной Вами ссылке.
На мой взгляд, пока это - гадание на кофейной гуще.
Если исследователь приведет действительно серьезные обоснования, можно будет об этом разговаривать.

Comment: Вот отрывок сообщения:
Пагел рассказывает, что даже сейчас, среди европейских языков выделяется общий корень слова “I”: I – в английском, Ich – в немецком, Je – во французском, Io – в итальянском, Yo – в испанском. В протоязыке в этом значение употреблялось слово, которое сейчас ближе по значению к английскому местоимению “me”, а звучало как - “meh” или “beh”.

Comment: Ценность данной пары в том, что она не учтена словарем Фасмера. А, значит, и всеми прочими этимологами, "повторяющими" за ним свои словари.